# drop alternate columns of csv file using pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, read.csv

```py
print("cols",cols)
for i in range(0, cols,2):
    print("i",i);
    dataset.drop(dataset.columns[dataset.iloc[:,i]], axis='1', inplace=True)
    
dataset.head()
```

Here cols is total number of columns in csv file( i am reading from my system).

Columns names in csv files is similar to `['time', 'Link 1 Bytes','L1 unit', 'Link 2 bytes','L2 unit', 'Link 2 bytes', 'L3 unit']`.
Here time, L1 unit, L2 unit and L3 unit plays no roles and are in text values.

Hence I want to keep only numerical value columns.
Can anyone please help.

Moreover, I am getting the error, " IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Comment: "Hence I want to keep only numerical value columns." --> you are looking for the `select_dtypes` pandas function : `dataset.select_dtypes(include = "number")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: For dropping alternative items from list of columns;

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
res = [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i % 2 != 0]
```

Solution 2: If want to drop columns with "unit" in it;

```
col_drop = [col for col in df.columns if "unit" in col]
df1 = df.drop(col_drop,axis=1)
```

Solution 3: If want to keep only numeric columns;

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
```

Hope this Helps...